# Using matrices in firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase

After a while setting a int matrix `int[][] Matrix = new int[4][4]` I cannot upload it to firebase `mDatabase.child("room_1").setValue(Matrix);`because Arrays are not supported. 
The reason I use `int[][]` is to be able to add integers using `Matrix[2][3] += 1`
What data types are compatible with firebase and can handle those types of addition? 
Thanks.

---

I could not get it working the way I wanted with lists nor Long, so I have used `int matrix[][]` and updated the db with `setValue(matrix[index][index2])` in a one per one basis.

For getting the database into the matrix I used two while loops nested that checks every value and puts it in the matrix 
The following function gets the Object

```
public void SyncWDB(Object dbValue) {
        ArrayList aList = (ArrayList) dbValue;
        //I hardcoded the matrix dimensions just for testing 
        int e = 0;
        int i = 0;
        while (e < 5) {
            ArrayList temp = (ArrayList) aList.get(e);
            while (i < 4) {
                Long temp2 = Long.parseLong(String.valueOf(temp.get(i)));
                int temp3 = temp2.intValue();
                // Matrix is a class variable
                Matrix[e][i] = temp3;

                i++;
            }
            i = 0;
            e++;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

From [firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/save-data#basic_write).

> ### Basic write operations
>
> For basic write operations, you can use `setValue()` to save data to a
>   specified reference, replacing any existing data at that path. You can
>   use this method to:
>
> 1. Pass types that correspond to the available JSON types as follows:
>
>    - String
>    - Long
>    - Double
>    - Boolean
>    - Map
>    - List
> 2. Pass a custom Java object, if the class that defines it has a
>      default constructor that takes no arguments and has public getters
>      for the properties to be assigned.

---

I strongly recommend you to go with the second option and, again, [firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/save-data#basic_write) will help you a lot on understanding how to do it.

If you still want to go with the "directly set", you could use a 2 dimensional List.

```
List<List<Integer>> listOfLists = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answers, I had sow that in the docs and tried with `list[] [] ` but I couldn't do the additions that way, I will try with your suggestions

Comment: @AlejandroPacheco Let me know if my answer was helpful or if you still have any doubts. Thanks.

Comment: I could not get it working the way I wanted with lists nor Long, so I have used `int matrix[][]` and updated the db with `setValue(matrix[index][index2])` in a one per one basis.